# Connect Dual Monitor to AMD radeon 6670

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have a AMD radeon 6670, it has a display port, DVI-I and a VGA output. I have 2 VGA monitors with no other ports.

Is it possible to connect two VGA cables to this with an adapter and will the card support 2 VGA outputs?

Answer (score 1):

- Display port is digital only. You cannot connect VGA to it without some active component which understands display port and translates it to VGA.
- DVI-I is a version of DVI which has both the regular digital DVI output and the pins for ancient analog output. It your card supplies the analog part then you can use a simple convertor to connect VGA to this.

Given the choice between an expensive convertor or a cheap mere plug style convertor I would do for a DVI-I to VGA plug.

Mind you, VGA is old (1985-ish). It was replaced by DVI.
DVI is old, it has been replaced by DHMI and DP.

So if you want to add a third monitor in the future then consider a DP port monitor (or whatever is relevant at that time) rather than using 28 year old standard<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>*</sup>VGA was introduced in 1987. Today it is 2015. That is 28 years!

Comment: There's a VERY good chance the onboard port is DVI-D even if its a DVI-I style socket. If its DVI-I, DVI-A -> VGA connectors would work and are quite literally cheap as chips.

Answer (score 0):

Hook the VGA output to one monitor. Use an adapter to convert DisplayPort to VGA, and use that to connect the other monitor.

Comment: Will i need an active DisplayPort?

Comment: An active "converter" would be nessisary to convert DP to VGA.  From the wiki "VGA adapters are powered by the DisplayPort connector"  So it looks like the DP could provide the power (unlike DVI-D digital only onversion)   The wiki sort of using incorrect terminology , as an adapter suggest adapting to the connection, and a "converter" would be the actual need. To convert from digital to analog.